# How can I create a symbolic link with Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

Using Inno Setup, is there any way to create a symbolic link from one directory in my `{app}` folder to another? For example:

`{app}\MySymbolicLink` => `{app}\MyLinkedFolder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to invoke the [`mklink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; \
    Parameters: "/C mklink /D ""{app}\MySymbolicLink"" ""{app}\MyLinkedFolder"""
```

---

You can also call [`CreateSymbolicLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsymboliclinkw) from `[Code]` section.

Similarly to how `CreateHardLink` is called in [Create a hardlink with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32960082/850848).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it was so easy to invoke the command prompt from Inno Setup. Thanks for your help!