# How can I reproduce symbolic link in Inno Setup on the target machine?

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, symlink

I include a symbolic link from the source machine into Inno Setup. When running the installer on the target machine, it deploys a copy of the source file in place of the symbolic link. How do I make the installer preserve the symbolic links?

```
[Files]
Source: "c:\source path*"; Excludes:"*.log"; DestDir: "C:\destination path"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "install" a symbolic link using the `Files` section. Inno Setup does not support symlinks.

You have to create the link explicitly on the target machine. For that, see [How can I create a symbolic link with Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48027881/850848)

To avoid installing the symlinked file twice,  you may need to exclude it from the installation using the [`Excludes` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=Excludes).

Comment: OK i got it now!
thank you very much!
I appreciate it!!